# How to get exact accented characters in outlook mail?

Tags: shell, unix, outlook

There is a requirement in which we have given list of bad characters(Ñ,ñ,Â,Ã±,...). And have to check and replace these characters with correct characters. Input file is with extension .dat.
If any new bad character is encountered then mail should be send mentioning new bad character(Ñ,ñ,Â,Ã±,...) found.
I am able to read and replace characters(created a mapping file for replacing). But for new bad characters while sending mail, these characters get changed to some other characters like ÃT(replaced for Ù).
Sending mail using shell's mail command. Bad characters would be send in mail body.

Thanks